# Cakephp's $this->autorender=false doesn't show entire string as expected

Tags: php, view, controller, cakephp-2.0, ovh

For ajax purpose, I'm trying to render a string from a Cakephp (2.8.5) controller without any view. To achieve this, I usually code, then use `$this->render = false` before the `return` and it works fine.

I uploaded the website on OVH (a french Internet Service Provider) and something's wrong, the rendered string doesn't behave as it should. It's not displayed as intended until it reaches a certain size.

To demonstrate the issue, i prepared a dynamic page online (you can change the 15 by any number, below 15 generates the issue) :
http://darxnake.fr/nadau3/pages/test/15

code is very simple :

**PagesController.php :**

```
class PagesController extends AppController {
    public function test($nb=1) {

        $str = "";
        $char = "o";
        $upper = true;

        for ($i=0; $i < $nb; $i++) {
            $str .= $upper ? strtoupper($char) : strtolower($char);
            $upper = $upper ? false : true;
        }

        $this->autoRender = false;

        return $str;
    }
}
```

Changing the last `return` by a `die` displays the full string, but I don't like `die` in controllers, doesn't feel like it's how it should be done.

This code works offline on my computer (Windows / uWamp) and I can't understand what's wrong. I suspect something from OVH, but can't be sure and don't know where to look. Here is the phpinfo for this host : http://darxnake.fr/nadau3/pages/info/

Can you please help me find out what's going on ? Thank you.

**Edit :**

Finaly did find what's causing the issue. Cakephp2 sends an HTTP Header called `Content-Length` with every response. While the passed size is accurate (14 passed to header for 14 characters asked in the code), rendered string is stripped. If I disable this header in CakePhp lib (/lib/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php), render string is fixed.

On my local pc, this header is not sent (don't know why) and on OVH with the very same test but with CakePhp 3, this header is not sent either.

So I disabled it the lib code and problem is gone, though if someone could please explain what happens, and if I did something wrong disabling it. I'm not very familiar with HTTP headers...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why but after using;

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

You can't get actual result exactly..I have faced that situation too.
In my case I removed autoRender and worked fine.
Try removing that line if not compulsory.